# Emacs is very slow when navigating into a specific C++ file

Tags: emacs, navigation, slowdown

I am in holidays and I want to do some Emacs !

With Emacs 26.1 on my Xeon Debian box, I have some problems with the following C++ file:
https://github.com/mamedev/mame/blob/master/src/devices/cpu/z80/z80.cpp (which is part of the Mame project).

When I open it and press several times the "page down" key, Emacs seems to hang. In fact 100% of the cpu is consumed during 10 to 15 seconds. Then it works well.

My Emacs config is nearly empty.

The code is a little special as is contains lot of macros, but I can open it and navigate into it without problem with vim or VSCode.
What should I do ?
Thanks !

Comment: I'd suggest removing the [c++] tag. Your issue is not about the programming language itself. By leaving it in, you'll attract plenty of people interested in C++, who don't necessarily care about emacs and may downvote or even vote to close. I believe your target audience is emacs gurus.

Comment: I've seen syntax highlighting cause such issues in the past.  If that's the problem here you might want to have a look at your [font-lock](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Turning-on-syntax-highlighting.html) settings.

Comment: You are right. If I turn off syntax highlighting, it run smoother. But then, I loose syntax highlighting ! And the file is not so big, around 3600 lines ...

Comment: I can confirm this, both in 26.3 and in a recent Emacs build from the master branch.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` and see whether the cc-mode maintainer can identify why this file is causing that much of a problem.

Comment: report-emacs-bug done !

Comment: This is bug#42490